# Find consecutive working dates for each employee

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, gaps-and-islands

In SQL 2000 I have a table that contains the following:

```
ID Date WorkingTime EmployeeID
```

For August, this table would contain 200 employees with dates of 8/1 - 8/31. I need to find out what is the MIN date of the first 5 consecutive days of working time for each employee starting at the day passed in and going backward.

For Example:
If employee 123 looked as follows and 8/10/2013 was passed in:

```
ID Date WorkingTime EmployeeID
1  8/1      1           123 
2  8/2      0           123
3  8/3      0           123
4  8/4      1           123
5  8/5      1           123
6  8/6      1           123
7  8/7      1           123
8  8/8      1           123
9  8/9      0           123
10 8/10     1           123
```

The result would be 8/4. This needs to be done all at once for all of the employees in the table, so they would all have different min dates, all starting on 8/10 since that was the date that was passed into the query. This table is very large in real life and contins many dates and employees, not just in Auguest. I thought about using a cursor to go through all of this but I think that would be really slow. I was also thinking of adding all of the working times to a temp table and doing a datediff on them to find the consecutive 5 with a datediff of 1, but I wasn't quite sure how to execute that. Is there a better way I am not thinking of?

Comment: Really using SQL Server 2000?  :(

Comment: Looking for a sum of WorkingTime = 5 might be part of the solution.

Comment: @Goat CO, tell me about it.

Comment: Hey SQL Server 2000 was pretty awesome... for its time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
    ID      INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    [Date]  SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL,
    WorkingTime INT NOT NULL,
    EmployeeID  INT NOT NULL
);
INSERT  @MyTable ([Date], WorkingTime, EmployeeID)
-- First employee
SELECT  '20130801', 1, 123 UNION ALL 
SELECT  '20130802', 0, 123 UNION ALL 
SELECT  '20130803', 0, 123 UNION ALL 
SELECT  '20130804', 1, 123 UNION ALL 
SELECT  '20130805', 1, 123 UNION ALL 
SELECT  '20130806', 1, 123 UNION ALL 
SELECT  '20130807', 1, 123 UNION ALL 
SELECT  '20130808', 1, 123 UNION ALL 
SELECT  '20130809', 0, 123 UNION ALL 
SELECT  '20130810', 1, 123 UNION ALL
-- Second employee
SELECT  '20130801', 1, 126 UNION ALL 
SELECT  '20130802', 1, 126 UNION ALL 
SELECT  '20130803', 1, 126 UNION ALL 
SELECT  '20130804', 1, 126 UNION ALL 
SELECT  '20130805', 1, 126 UNION ALL 
SELECT  '20130806', 0, 126 UNION ALL 
-- Third employee
SELECT  '20130801', 0, 127 UNION ALL 
SELECT  '20130802', 0, 127 UNION ALL 
SELECT  '20130803', 1, 127 UNION ALL 
SELECT  '20130804', 1, 127 UNION ALL 
SELECT  '20130805', 0, 127 UNION ALL 
SELECT  '20130806', 0, 127;
```

--

```
DECLARE @Results TABLE
(
    EmployeeID  INT NOT NULL,
    DaysDiff    INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeID, DaysDiff), -- This is a "clustered index"/index organized table
    RowNum      INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    [Date]      SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL
);
INSERT  @Results (EmployeeID, DaysDiff, [Date])
SELECT  x.EmployeeID,   
        DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, x.[Date]) AS DaysDiff,
        x.[Date]
FROM    @MyTable x
WHERE   x.WorkingTime = 1
/*
This ORDER BY clause and the clustered index (PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeID, DaysDiff))
should give a hint to SQL Server so that 
RowNum IDENTITY values will be generated in this order: EmployeeID, DaysDiff

Note #1: There is not 100% guarantee that insert order will be the same as 
ORDER BY x.EmployeeID, DaysDiff
and 
clustered index key (EmployeeID, DaysDiff)

Note #2: This INSERT INTO table with identity column simulates the ROW_NUMBER function
which is available starting with SQL2005.
*/
ORDER BY x.EmployeeID, DaysDiff
OPTION (MAXDOP 1); -- It minimizes the risk of messing up the order of RowNum

SELECT  y.EmployeeID, MAX(y.GroupStartDate) AS FirstGroupStartDate
FROM
(
    SELECT  x.EmployeeID, x.GroupID, 
            MIN(x.[Date]) AS GroupStartDate, MAX(x.[Date]) AS GroupEndDate,
            DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(x.[Date]), MAX(x.[Date]))+1 AS ContinuousDays
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  *, r.DaysDiff - r.RowNum AS GroupID
        FROM    @Results r
    ) x
    GROUP BY x.EmployeeID, x.GroupID
) y
WHERE y.ContinuousDays > 4
GROUP BY y.EmployeeID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Below query will give good start for what you want to achieve, modify the schema based on your tables.

SQL fiddle [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/21396)

@DateToPull - Date for which you want to pull data for.
 #TimeSheet is your original table
 #SubsetTimeSheet - table with subset of records from #TimeSheet table. Populated with  records from first of the month till passed date.

Note: This query can be written more efficiently with newer version of SQL Server.

```
  declare @DateToPull datetime
  select @DateToPull = '08/10/2013'

  if object_id('tempdb..#TimeSheet') is not null
     drop table #TimeSheet

  create table #TimeSheet
  (
     ID int identity(1, 1),
     EmployeeID int,
     [WorkDate] datetime,
     WorkingTime bit
  )

  insert into #TimeSheet(EmployeeID, [WorkDate], WorkingTime)
  select 123 , '08/01/2013', 0
  union all
  select 123 , '08/02/2013', 1
  union all
  select 123 , '08/03/2013', 0
  union all
  select 123 , '08/04/2013', 1
  union all
  select 123 , '08/05/2013', 1
  union all
  select 123 , '08/06/2013', 1
  union all
  select 123 , '08/07/2013', 1
  union all
  select 123 , '08/08/2013', 1
  union all
  select 123 , '08/09/2013', 0
  union all
  select 123 , '08/10/2013', 1
  union all
  select 123 , '08/11/2013', 1
  union all
  select 123 , '08/12/2013', 1
  union all
  select 123 , '08/13/2013', 1
  union all
  select 123 , '08/14/2013', 1
  union all
  select 123 , '08/15/2013', 0
  union all
  select 123 , '08/16/2013', 1
  union all
  select 123 , '08/17/2013', 1
  union all
  select 123 , '08/18/2013', 1
  union all
  select 123 , '08/19/2013', 1
  union all
  select 123 , '08/20/2013', 1

  if object_id('tempdb..#SubsetTimeSheet') is not null
     drop table #SubsetTimeSheet

  create table #SubsetTimeSheet
  (
     EmployeeID int,
     [WorkDate] datetime,
     WorkingTime bit
  )

  insert into #SubsetTimeSheet(EmployeeID, [WorkDate], WorkingTime)
  select EmployeeID, [WorkDate], WorkingTime
  from #TimeSheet
  where
         datediff(dd, [WorkDate], @DateToPull) >= 0
     and datediff(dd, DATEADD(dd, -(DAY(@DateToPull)-1), @DateToPull), [WorkDate]) >= 0
     and WorkingTime = 1
  order by    
     EmployeeID,
     [WorkDate] desc

  select A.EmployeeID, max(E.WorkDate) WorkDate
  from 
     #SubsetTimeSheet A
     inner join #SubsetTimeSheet B on datediff(dd, A.[WorkDate] - 1, B.WorkDate) = 0 and A.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID
     inner join #SubsetTimeSheet C on datediff(dd, A.[WorkDate] - 2, C.WorkDate) = 0 and A.EmployeeID = C.EmployeeID
     inner join #SubsetTimeSheet D on datediff(dd, A.[WorkDate] - 3, D.WorkDate) = 0 and A.EmployeeID = D.EmployeeID
     inner join #SubsetTimeSheet E on datediff(dd, A.[WorkDate] - 4, E.WorkDate) = 0 and A.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
  group by
        A.EmployeeID
```